# How to add Fresco source into another project via Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build, build.gradle, fresco

I can build Fresco from source as directed on [its own official site](http://frescolib.org/docs/building-from-source.html).

However I cannot add its source as a project into my `build.gradle`.

When trying to build the project it throws an exception as the below:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':ReactAndroid'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':ReactAndroid:_debugPublish'.
      > Configuration with name 'default' not found.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':ReactAndroid:compile'.
      > Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

Is there any chance to overcome this issue?

`settings.gradle` file of the app:

```
include ':app'

include ':fresco'
project(':fresco').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../fresco')
```

`build.gradle` file of the app:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.+"

        compile project(':ReactAndroid')
        compile project(':fresco')
}
...
```

Some explanations:

- Fresco has a main [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/v1.3.0/build.gradle) file that serves to other modules' `build.gradle` files
- Also it exposes a lot of modules in its own [`settings.gradle`](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/v1.3.0/settings.gradle) file. I don't know how to call and use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [Gradle Composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/userguide/composite_builds.html), a feature added in Gradle 3. There are many ways to configure it but to include a local build of a third party library like fresco, you can set it up via the cli:

`./gradlew assembleDebug --include-build <path/to/local/fresco/>`

Since it keeps the projects separate, the structure of fresco's build doesn't matter and you don't need to modify your react project's `settings.gradle` or `build.gradle`. The included build will provide the dependency and replace the remote version.